# JSON Object is null although defined before inside a AsyncTask class?

Tags: java, android, mysql, json, android-asynctask

I tried to get a connection to MySQL database by collecting the information in JSON format. My code receives these information. I created a class which extends`AsyncTask` and in my `onPostExecute` class I want to save the complete `JSONArray` to a different `JSONArray` outside of the `AsyncTask`class. Will doing that I do not get an error message, but once I want to work with this Object my code crashes and I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException` and my new JSON Array is null.
Can anybody help me?

```
class task extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void>
{    
   InputStream is = null ;

   protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        String url_select = "http://pois.lima-city.de/test1.php";

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url_select);

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            //read content
            is =  httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                sb.append(line+"\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }

        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
        try {


            LatLng coordinates;
            String between = "";
            JSONArray JarrayP = new JSONArray(result);
            myJSONArray = JarrayP;
          } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }
    }
```

PS: It is inside an other class.

Comment: Are you sure you're using myJSONArray **after** it's been initialised in onPostExecute? Remember that you're doing an AsyncTask, which means your myJSONArray won't be ready straight away. For proper context, include more relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently returning `Void` in your `doInBackground(String...)`. That's why you're getting null in `onPostExecute`. Change your class to :

```
public class YourTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
 ....
```

Then in `doInBackground()`:

```
....
return result;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the point of using that `result` string, if you use it only for creating that json array. Try to return `sb.toString()` (instead of null) from `doInBackground`. For this, you need to modify your asynctask. Your third generic variable should be String, and you need to set a String parameter in your `postExecute` header. Then create your json array with that string.